# jspdf browser size seems to effect pdf size

Tags: jspdf

If I create a pdf with JsPDF the browser size seems to effect the size of the text inside the pdf. The code to create te pdf.

```
 var pdf = new jsPDF();

 //To split on multiple pages
 var options = {
      pagesplit: true
 }
 pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById("test"), options,function() {
      pdf.save('test.pdf');
 });
```

And the html

```
<div id="pdf_container">
    <div id="pdf_top">
        <h1>My report</h1>
    </div>
   <div>
        <p>some text</p>
        <p>some text</p>  
        <p>some text</p>
        <p>some text</p>
        <p>some text</p>
        <p>some text</p>
    </div>  
</div>
```

The link to the result of both pdf.save: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBGqg.jpg

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JsPDF uses the current size of the div that you are sending to the function.

You must to give a fixed style and size to each element that you wants to convert to PDF, to get always the same file. Try with this css, and you can play with differents widths and font sizes until you get the style that you want.

**myStlye.css**

```
#pdf_container{
    width:500px;
    font-size:15px;
}
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks!